# "Trainer" is to "trainee" as "mentor" is to what?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, suffixes, analogy, er-ee

What do you call someone who is being *mentored*? Is it *mentoree* or *mentee*? Does the term *student* or *pupil* imply a context outside the business environment?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. The lack of experience and/or knowledge is expected on the side of "the opposite of mentor." What is the problem with "student" or "pupil" then?

Comment: Not really an opposite, but "mentor" is usually associated with "pupil".

Comment: Ok I suppose what I trying to say is that using the term student or pupil implies a context outside of the business environment?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the question, as I believe you're looking for a term for the _recipient_ of mentoring, which is different from the _opposite_ of a mentor, which would be someone who leads you astray rather than guides you on the right path.

Comment: @aaamos , absolutely correct :) a mentee , student , a pupil may stand opposite a mentor in the physical sense of the word only ...

Comment: @ray: I'm reminded of the Inigo Montoya quote, "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." ;-)

Comment: I've been mentored by others whilst I was a junior software engineer and then in later life mentored junior software engineers.  The point is that the person being mentored would (in my experience) be referred to by their job title/role rather than anything like a mentee or pupil.

Comment: A few years back I worked for a while in a company where my job title was significantly *senior* to the guy who was assigned as my mentor. He just knew more than me about certain things the company specialised in that I needed to know. We were both happy with the name of his role, and I wouldn't have minded being called a *mentoree* if it had ever come up, but I certainly wouldn't have expected to be called his *pupil/student*.

Comment: The mentor mentors the mentored, but I also liked the response of "protege".

Comment: "Mentor" does not imply a business environment; it's a general term for someone who acts as a role model, guide, or teacher. "Mentee" is just as general. Using different/more specific words can imply a context, but to just describe the relationship I recommened "mentee"

Answer (score 52):

I think you may be looking for [*protege*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/protege):

> **protege** — a person who receives support and protection from an influential patron who furthers the protege's career

Comment: But *patron* is very different from *mentor*.  A *patron* provides money and influence, while a *mentor* is normally an expert in the pupil's own field and gives advice.  The Pope was a *patron* of Michaelangelo who commissioned him to create many works of art, but the Pope could not be a *mentor* as he had no artistic experience of his own.

Comment: @Nate: *Mentor* is used today in the same way *patron* used to be. These days *patron* has come to mean someone who donates money to an institution (or individual), not someone who brings someone along in society or in a career.

Comment: +1. Came here to say this. We can get hung up on the particulars of this particular definition from this particular source all we want, but that doesn't change the fact that *mentor/protégé* is *the* word pair that everyone actually uses. Just check, oh I dunno, *Seinfeld*, or *Sex and the City*, or really, *every TV series ever*.

Comment: @RegDwight: Despite the fact that I expect *mentee* to be displaced by *mentoree* pretty soon, it's the more common of the two right now. And checking Google Books for *mentor* paired with *mentee/protege*, in 1990-1995 I find 1550/4360, in 1995-2000 4320/6490, and in 2000-2005 9880/8950. I didn't bother with 2005-2010 because it'll be incomplete, but it's obvious *protege* has already been displaced. The only question now is whether/how soon *mentoree* will take the top slot.

Comment: This works in the context of mentor in the workplace, but what about non-professional mentors? The word mentor can apply to role models in general, not necessarily a more experience co-worker.

Comment: Protege doesn't work since the mentee is not "protected" by the mentor nor does the mentor-mentee relationship usually last beyond a training period. When I became a dispatcher, I had a "mentor" that I could ask questions of until I got the hang of things and passed the annual qualification. Once I was signed off, he was no longer my mentor; he was my co-worker. I was never his protege.

Comment: **deshi** might be more accurate, since we are mixing up root cultures and all

Comment: @AnWulf: Was that coworker really a mentor, then? Or just a trainer?

Comment: I think protege connotes that the mentor vouches for the potential of the person being mentored.  Depending on the context, that may not be a desired connotation.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 ... No, I had a trainer from the training department responsible to sign me off when the time came. Let's not forgot the meaning of a mentor: noun • an experienced and trusted adviser: he was her friend and mentor until his death in 1915.
• an experienced person in a company, college, or school who trains and counsels new employees or students.

Comment: *Protege* is the answer. I am the best fisherman. If I like a person and want to teach my techniques, I am the mentor amd he or she the protege.

Answer (score 33):

Some businesses provide less experienced staff with mentors. I have heard the mentors refer to their "mentees". Wikipedia says this is a [recent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentee) term.

Answer (score 18):

There's nothing at all wrong with [mentoree](http://www.unwords.com/unword/mentoree.html), as [these 1270 written instances in Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=mentoree&ei=L6zdVbSIKqKL7AbDnqqwBw) show. The fact that most dictionaries don't explicitly list this particular inflection of *mentor* is of no consequence - it's used often enough already, and will always be understood even at first sight.

*Mentee* also [occurs quite often](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=mentee&ei=h6zdVfeJI9GM7Aap5aHwBA) in written form - but I have to say I don't like that version, and it seems to me it won't always be so readily understood. Bearing in mind that what a *mentor* does is *mentoring*, not *menting*, I think it's a badly-formed coinage anyway.

I would also point out that *to mentor* as a verb form [barely existed before the last couple of decades](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20mentor,mentored&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), so it's hardly surprising more exotic inflections still encounter some resistance. But I've no doubt the erroneous *mentee* will die off, and "regular" *mentoree* will soon be firmly established.

EDIT: My Chambers dictionary 1983 has only the short entry *"a wise counsellor"* for *mentor*. The latest 2011 edition is much expanded, fully describing the "office mentor" role, *and* noting its use as a verb. I don't have the two intermediate editions to hand, to say when the verb use was first noted. The point is, we're looking at rapidly changing language here; dictionaries may not always keep up.

I also tip my hat to @horatio for pointing out that since the word comes from [Mentor](http://www.nickols.us/mentor.pdf), counsellor to Homer's Odysseus (later, tutor to his son), arguably OP's answer is **Odysseus** (or **Telemachus**)

Comment: You may not like "mentee", but it's certainly [in wider use than "mentoree"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentee%2Cmentoree&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), as the ngrams and [google book search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mentee&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) show.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: Well you only have to look at the upvotes here for *protege* - twice those for silves89's *mentee*, and four times my *mentoree* - to see that most people like what they know. But I'm quite certain if you plot the frequency of occurence for all three words over the past 30 years, you'll see that *mentoree* is coming up fast on the inside track. Given its "correct" relationship to the newly-emerged verb *"to mentor"*, I'd bet any money that in another 30 years time *mentoree* will be the standard form. Whether we few here at ELU like it or not - it's just a line on a graph.

Comment: If _tutoree_ is OK, so is _mentoree._ Mentor's trademark rights have lapsed, so we don't need a capital M; it's a common noun now, hanging around business schools, and it's been inflecting like a verb lately. The _-ee_ suffix selects [Absolutives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ergativity.pdf), which means direct objects of transitive verbs (and subjects of intransitive). Both verbs are transitive, and their direct objects (the people being tutored or mentored) are selected. Perfectly straighforward; the only strange thing is a proper noun  becoming a verb, like _lynch_ or _boycott._

Comment: @John Lawler: I don't understand that word *absolutive* (or the references to *ergative* languages that abound when I try to Google it). Does it effectively identify the "passive recipient" form (e.g. - *trainee*) as opposed to the "active agent" (e.g. - *trainer*)? Anyway, I quite agree a significant factor here is that the noun has become a standard verb, which is what makes me think the person being mentored will soon be routinely called the "mentoree" without people feeling they're just using office jargon.

Comment: Ergative phenomena occur in most languages; so do Accusative phenomena. English mostly uses an Accusative system marking the Direct Object as a special case that occurs only with transitive verbs. Ergative systems mark the Transitive Agent Subject as a special case that occurs only with transitives. At the bottom of the linked page a couple of minor ergative phenomena in English are mentioned, and the _-ee_ suffix is one. That's all.

Comment: @John Lawler: oic - thanks for that. I think I've got it. My understanding now is English isn't really an "ergative" language, but we have a few case markers that would be far more central to certain other languages.

Comment: It's just a way of coding arguments in clauses. Transitive clauses have two arguments, so they have to be distinguished some way. There are two main ways, the Accusative system and the Ergative system. English is mostly Acc, with a few Erg; Dyirbal, on the other hand, marks nouns with an Erg system and pronouns with an Acc. In an Ergative system, you could say there's no concept of "Subject", because transitive subjects are ergative, while intransitive ones are absolutive. Contrariwise, we don't have a concept of "Absolutive".

Answer (score 13):

I know that **mentee** is common in American English, and is used by a variety of mentoring programs. One example of such is the US Department of Health and Human Services's [Mentoring Program](https://mentoring.hhs.gov/mentors.aspx).

I know several people that work in this field, and they all use the word mentee.

Although the term *mentee* is relatively new and not [near as popular as mentor](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentor%2Cmentee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it far [outshadows the use of mentoree](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentoree%2Cmentee&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

A few other organizations that use "mentee":

- [MassMentoring](http://www.massmentors.org/), a Boston-based mentoring program
- [Big Brothers Big Sisters](http://www.bbbs.org/), one of the most well-known mentoring programs
- [NASA](http://fpd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Code400_Orientation_Session.doc), the US's space agency
- [Harvard](http://www.gse.harvard.edu/alumni_friends/sami/mentees.html), one of the world's most prestigious schools

Answer (score 8):

I think ***apprentice*** may be as good as anything.  It's certainly used much more than mentee/mentoree.  It's also pretty accurate and widely understood.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are asking for a word for a person guided by a mentor. "Student" or "pupil" perhaps, but they have the implication of teaching. Perhaps "acolyte" or "disciple", though the latter implies devotion, and is used for follwers of a religous leader.
Mentee is indeed "modern" and not widely used.

Answer (score 4):

[Mentee](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mentee) may be in the dictionary, but it is not in common usage (in my experience).  My browser spell-check doesn't even recognize it :) It'll probably get the point across, though it may earn some odd looks.

Mentoring someone is not strictly a teaching relationship, so student and pupil don't quite fit.   Especially in a business setting, a mentor is often just there to help the person get settled, show them particulars of your business and answer questions.  This is not "teaching" them to do their job except in the loosest sense.

In short, I don't think there's a single nice term that mirrors trainee.

Comment: *Mentee* shows up in the bureaucratic nonsense---tenure progress packets, grant application, etc---written in US academic circles.

Comment: At work we use _mentee_ with only a little bit of tongue in cheek.

Comment: Down-voted for saying that your spell checker doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @HotLicks - It was a joking observation (hence the smiley) - I did point out that it was in the actual dictionary.  But if you feel that detracts enough from the actual answer enough to warrant a down-vote, that's your prerogative.

Answer (score 2):

Mentee sounds, to this linguist, like a perfectly understandable neologism based on the trainer-trainee analogy, never mind that the verb root ment- to which the -ee suffix is added does not exist in its own right.

Comment: In *trainer/trainee*, as with *payee, employee, mortgagee, appointee*, the root verb is clearly identified. And in the last two we rarely encounter the *-er/-or* forms anyway, suggesting the verb itself is far more important than the derived *"active agent"* form in determining the acceptability of a *"passive recipient"* form. Given the recent rapid rise in popularity of the verb **to mentor**, and the implausibility of **to ment** ever catching on, I really do think that once the general speaking public get to grips with this, *mentee* will be quietly killed off as "office jargon".

Comment: a quick look at the word `mentor` shows that is was the proper name of a character in Odysseus. So the -or suffix is coincidental and not latin, which suggests to me that -ee suffix is not strictly correct. (??) However, the -or/-ee combo punch is well established. I suppose that the proper word to use would be `Odysseus`.

Comment: @horatio: haha, nice one! My Chambers '83 confirms, but has only the very short entry *"a wise counsellor"* for *mentor*. Latest '11 issue is much expanded, fully describing the "office mentor" role, *and* noting its use as a verb. We really are witnessing language in the making here, so it's a shame you didn't get your alternative in early so it could have become established by now!

Comment: ...also, note that in all other *agent/recipient* pairings, the agent version is formed by adding *-er/-or* to a pre-existing verb. Obviously the relevant verb here didn't even exist when *mentor* as "agent" started out, but quite possibly in a few generations people will assume *that's* the one that isn't "strictly correct". (they'll be saying it should really have been **mentorer** :)

Comment: I found mentee back to 1943 ... so it is hardly a neologism. It's been around long enuff to make to make into the OED: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mentee Regardless, mentor stands as a word without a verb root so there is no grounds to demand a verb root for mentee.