# Word for "person that I supervise"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, er-ee

What is the best word to refer to *the person that I (directly) supervise*, in the context of a corporate workplace? The closest I can think of is *employee*, but that doesn't directly convey a direct supervisor relationship.

Other options I can think of are *apprentice* (usually used to refer exclusively to someone who is still learning where I come from), *underling* (patronizing), and *worker* (again not specific).

For example when describing a project:

> My *employee* designed the front-end of the system while I worked on the critical business logic.

Comment: The workers being supervised don't have a role of being supervised, unlike the supervisor whose role is that of supervision. That's why it's difficult to find an opposite for supervisor.

Comment: Well, I suppose if _underling_ is too "patronizing," that would rule out _minion_...

Comment: @J.R.: And most likely *hireling, lackey, menial, retainer, dogsbody, skivvy, gofer* and all the other ways your boss actually refers to you when he's talking to *other* bosses.

Comment: Could you provide more context? Your options suggest a work environment.

Comment: Isn't *subordinate* the word?

Comment: @coleopterist I've added some more context to the question.

Comment: Personally, I like to call them "minions", but only in private.

Comment: _Serf_ might be worth reviving.

Answer (score 24):

[***direct-report***](http://smartblogs.com/leadership/2012/09/27/25-tips-managing-first-direct-reports/) is often used.

> *I'm having a meeting on Tuesday for all my* **direct reports**.

Answer (score 16):

From Merriam-Webster, a *[supervisee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supervisee)* is *a person being supervised*. The word has over 600,000 google hits, so it isn't really outdated.

Comment: IMHO this sounds definitely too old-fashioned for the indicated context. In a reference I would use the person's (first) name or refer to "my direct report", if necessary.

Comment: Do you work in IT (as in "my supervisee designed the front-end of the system ...")? I think the term may serve better in other contexts, but of course there may not be a definite "best" (counted or weighed :) answer.

Comment: And the plural, "supervisees" is even less often use.

I have people that I supervise but who are not necessarily team members or direct reports. They're not my employees, and they're not contractors. They are consortium partner members and freelancers of a contracting firm. So it's hard for me to come up w/ a word that encompasses this set.

Answer (score 14):

What about 'subordinate'?  Perhaps a tinge too militaristic, but it is very close in my mind.

Comment: Subordinate is *anyone* falling below the supervisor in the hierarchy;  the OP is asking for those being directly supervised.

Comment: Not a word, but a phrase *immediate subordinate* comes to mind!

Comment: @Jim, good point. Perhaps someone with Greek or Latin fluency can make up a word for us with the precise meaning OP intended.

Answer (score 10):

Specific context is important because amongst my friends there are the following supervisor/supervised relationships:

**Team Lead / Team Member**

**Office Manager / Staff Member**

**Manager / Direct Report**

**Unit Coordinator / Unit Staff Member**

Answer (score 6):

Someone who is *in charge* of others has [*charges*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charge):

> **charge** *n*
>   5. One that is entrusted to another's care or management:

Comment: I imagine in practice most people speak of *my staff* if they really are "in charge". But OP's *supervise* implies a somewhat looser relationship - maybe little more than [mentor/mentoree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57314/), where it would still be credible for the *mentor* to speak of his *charge*.

Comment: All OP's examples are from the workplace: employee, apprentice, underling, worker, I'm not convinced *charge* is what he's looking for.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an employee but more like a ward or foster child.

Comment: Sorry but this context is completely different.

Comment: No, it's not. But have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Words not yet mentioned include *[aide](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aide#Noun)* (“An assistant”) and *[assistant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assistant#Noun)* (“A person who assists or helps someone else”).  For example, “My assistant designed the front-end of the system.”

*[Serf](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serf#Noun)* (“(strategy games) A worker unit”), *[slave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slave#Noun)*, and *[servant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/servant#Noun)* also have not been mentioned, but perhaps are no more acceptable than *minion, hireling, lackey, menial, retainer, dogsbody, skivvy, gofer* mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 2):

When speaking of my direct reports I use the term "staff". When speaking to my direct reports I use the term "team" or more specifically "team member". During annual reviews of direct reports I may reference my relationship to them as I'm their "supervisory support".

Avoid the term "subordinate" as that can have a "less than" connotation.

Answer (score 1):

When I hire people, I call them my *workers*.

Answer (score 0):

subordinate or supervisee.  I would try those

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes,it depends on the context. If you are presenting your subordinate to someone outside the business, i.e., a client or competitor the most magnanimous way is to say, "This is my associate." (Makes both of you look good)