# What is a term that measures whether a business organization is flat or hierarchical?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term that measures the level to which a business is flat or hierarchical in its organizational structure. For instance, if an org has an average of 10 employees per manager, it's fairly flat. If it has 2 per manager, it's fairly hierarchical.

Is there a measurement term for this N=2 or N=10 type of difference?

Comment: *Flatness,* perhaps?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. I survived 40 years in business organisations without knowing what it is.

Comment: A possibly-related term is  *[bushiness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bushiness)* (“The characteristic of being bushy”).   From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bushy#Adjective), *bushy* means “Like a bush in having many widely spread branches”.

Answer (score 3):

We have *deep* hierarchies and we have *flat* hierarchies, so rather unsurprisingly we have hierarchy *depth* or *flatness*, though the latter is a bit of a mouthful and the former is much more common.

Comment: The term "depth" seems to be used in scientific publications on the topic, see for example here: http://hbswk.hbs.edu/item/7000.html

Answer (score 1):

[***Direct reports***](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94416/87426) is used to refer to the people a manager supervises. The number of employees per manager can be referred to as the ***average number of direct reports***, or the ***average direct report count***. A flat organization will have a high *average direct report count*. This would be similar to how schools are sometimes compared according to their *average classroom size*.

When looking at an organization chart, it resembles an upside fan. In computing, the breadth of the fan is sometimes referred to as the ***fan-out***, or *fanout*. A flat organization will tend to have a *higher fan-out*, than one that is less flat.

Comment: I more often see it written "fanout". In fact I'm not sure if I've ever seen it as "fan out" until your answer. (But +1 regardless.)

Comment: @Charles: Ah, the two word version is a verb, used to tell people to go out and do something. Thanks for that.