# Who is the guardian of the protégé

Tags: word-choice

If protégé is the person who receives, so-to-speak, who is the giver? That is, what's the terms used for the person under whose patronage the protégé is?

Comment: Why the •s in *pro•té•gé*?

Comment: @Hugo I would guess they copied from a dictionary that uses bullets to note hyphenation points. They do not belong in the word itself though, so I have edited to remove them.

Comment: Jon Hanna is right. It was copied as such. But it looks ok now I guess

Comment: [“Trainer” is to “trainee” as “mentor” is to what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57314/trainer-is-to-trainee-as-mentor-is-to-what)

Comment: Mentor is to mentee

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The other person in the relationship with a protégé could be a *protector*, a *patron* or rarely a *patrona* (a female form of *patron*, normally not used, and hence implying that there is something significant in this protégé benefiting from a woman's patronage, hinting at a motivation for her generosity in the matter).

Most often though, the word is used to suggest that the protégé is learning from this person, and so that person is a *mentor*.

Certainly in the other direction, the person who benefits from a mentor is a *protégé*. (Unless again, we felt the need to distinguish a female *protégée* for some reason).

Comment: So does this imply that "patrona" has premeditative, or excogitative connotations (latter, in the least)?

Comment: Is there a seperate word for "female" protégée? What is it por favor?

Comment: Yes. It's a *very* rare word in Modern English (if we were writing of Ancient Rome and contrasting a patrona and a patronus, then such borrowing from Latin would be a different matter). We would 99% of the time use *patron* whether of a man or a woman. Choosing *patrona* would mean one of two things: 1. We were hinting that her being female was significant in some way (most likely that she finds her protégé attractive) or 2. We are showing off that we know the relatively rare word *patrona* ;)

Comment: You just used the separate word for a female protégée; it is *protégée*. Note the extra *e* compared to *protégé*. We would again though normally just use *protégé* for either sex. The choice to use *protégée* wouldn't be quite as pointed though, just rather old-fashioned (it used to be quite common) or perhaps a side-effect of the writer being familiar with the French from which it was borrowed and considering the extra *e* to be to proper way to use the word for that reason.

Comment: protégée.. indeed! sorry my bad :p thanks compadre : )

Comment: Isn't the female form of "patron" simply "matron", just as the female form of father is mother, and not "fathera"?

Comment: @Adriano. No. Even in classical Latin, *patronus* (patron, protector) had different meanings to *pater* (father), though they are related, and *patrona* was the female form of that.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

> The protégé and his or her [**mentor**](http://src.truman.edu/browse/display.asp?abs_id=2385&year=2010).

Comment: @JonHanna already mentioned that.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd We posted our answers at roughly the same time. Just ask him, he'll confirm.

Comment: @RyeBread, this is true. Certainly they were close enough together than I imagine Elian had started on this answer before they could see mine.

Answer (score 1):

The  **[patron](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Patron)** is the person in question:

a patron supports an protects  a protégé  usually to furthers his career.

Comment: Consistent with accepted answer. Gracious

Comment: @JonHanna already mentioned that.

Comment: @RyeBread ~ mine was the first answer, well before others! Please check before making comments and downvote.

Comment: @RyeBread, no Josh61 was there before me. As my answer states, I think *mentor* is much more often the appropriate word, but my answer includes this because there are indeed times when *patron* is the *mot juste*.