# What do you call a person who receives patronage?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm pretty sure there's a word for that. Unfortunately, searching for the antonym of patronage didn't yield any results.

Example sentence:

> Since I became a __ I haven't had to worry about money anymore.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/176770/2085

Comment: Shop keepers often say, “Thank you for your patronage” when they leave the store. So since I became a shopkeeper ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wholeheartedly recommend the Reverse Dictionary at onelook.com. Searching for [recipient of patronage](http://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=recipient%20of%20patronage) gives, among other less relevant suggestions, all of the following.

- protégé [probably the best word]
- client
- concern
- dependant
- favourite
- almsman
- beneficiary

Comment: I think "client" is the best choice.  It's commonly used in e.g. Roman history (where the patron/client relationship was a cultural norm), or international politics ("client state").  Pprotégé I think carries the connotation of a younger person being mentored,

Comment: @jamesqf - I too would associate a protégé with some transfer of skills rather than just money. I think I would find "client" in the example sentence somewhat confusing though. In common (non archaic) usage a client is a customer and someone paying for a service rather than receiving financial assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Not a word in common use in my experience but [patronee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/patronee) apparently exists.

Oxford Dictionaries includes the definition

> A recipient of patronage.
>
> Early 19th century; earliest use found in Sydney Smith (1771–1845)